# Sonarqube 5.1.2 with sonar-runner 2.4 doesnt display Groovy cobertura report

Tags: groovy, sonarqube, cobertura, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1.2

I have the below setup:

1. Sonarqube v5.1.2
2. Sonar Runner v2.4
3. Cobertura plugin for Sonarqube v1.6.3
4. Groovy plugin for Sonarqube v1.2

All are having the latest versions.

My project structure is like below:

```
ParentProject
|-sonar-project.properties
|- Grails Project A
|  |-sonar-project.properties
```

The ParentProject folder sonar-project.properties contains the below:

```
sonar.projectKey=ParentProject
sonar.projectName=Parent Project SONARQUBE
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.scm.url=scm:svn:https://server/svn/nv/frontend/grails/trunk
sonar.scm.provider=svn
sonar.language=grvy
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.grvy.coveragePlugin=cobertura
sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath=target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.web.file.suffixes=gsp

sonar.modules= ProjectA

# Settings for servicemodel#
ProjectA.sonar.projectBaseDir=./ProjectA
```

And inside ProjectA, we have the below sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.modules = projectA-groovymodule, projectA-javascriptmodule, projectA-webmodule

projectA-groovymodule.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.language=grvy
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.sources=grails-app/services,grails-app/controllers,grails-app/domain,grails-app/taglib,src/groovy
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.tests=test/unit,test/integration
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/test-reports
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.cobertura.reportPath = target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath=target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
projectA-groovymodule.sonar.grvy.coveragePlugin=cobertura

projectA-javascriptmodule.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
projectA-javascriptmodule.sonar.language=js
projectA-javascriptmodule.sonar.sources=grails-app, web-app/js
projectA-javascriptmodule.sonar.exclusions=web-app/js/lib/**/*

projectA-webmodule.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
projectA-webmodule.sonar.language=web
projectA-webmodule.sonar.sources=grails-app/views
```

I can confirm that the coverage.xml has been generated and is available on the folder specified in here.

The output of sonar-runner is as follows:

```
D:\Build\ParentProject>sonar-runner
D:\Apps\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_51 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\Apps\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: D:\Build\ParentProject\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_EN", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: D:\Build\ParentProject\.\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.2
16:05:40.180 INFO  - Load global repositories
16:05:40.644 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=470ms
16:05:40.689 INFO  - Server id: 20150930161227
16:05:40.696 INFO  - User cache: d:\gebruikers\user\.sonar\cache
16:05:40.888 INFO  - Install plugins
16:05:43.829 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
16:05:44.278 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbserver:port/db;instance=instance;SelectMethod=Cursor
16:05:48.516 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
16:05:56.529 INFO  - Load project repositories
16:05:57.659 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=1130ms
16:05:57.822 INFO  - Load project settings
16:05:59.033 INFO  - Load technical debt model
16:05:59.085 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
16:06:01.353 INFO  - -------------  Scan projectA-groovymodule
16:06:01.360 INFO  - Load module settings
16:06:01.731 INFO  - Language is forced to grvy
16:06:01.734 INFO  - Load rules
16:06:03.153 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\ProjectA
16:06:03.156 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule
16:06:03.158 INFO  - Source paths: grails-app/services, grails-app/controllers, grails-app/domain, grails-app/taglib, src/groovy
16:06:03.159 INFO  - Test paths: test/unit, test/integration
16:06:03.160 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_EN
16:06:03.161 INFO  - Index files
16:06:03.179 INFO  - Excluded sources:
16:06:03.181 INFO  -   web-app/js/jquery/**
16:06:03.314 INFO  - 18 files indexed
16:06:03.315 INFO  - 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
16:06:03.648 INFO  - Quality profile for grvy: profile
16:06:04.398 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
16:06:04.512 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=114ms
16:06:04.513 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
16:06:04.522 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=9ms
16:06:04.525 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
16:06:04.682 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=157ms
16:06:04.683 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
16:06:04.696 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=13ms
16:06:04.697 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
16:06:04.716 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=19ms
16:06:04.717 INFO  - Sensor CodeNarc
16:06:04.718 INFO  - Executing CodeNarc
16:06:05.580 INFO  - Loaded properties file in 67ms; 346 rules
16:06:05.641 INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groo
vymodule\codenarc\profile.xml]
16:06:07.175 INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.
16:06:09.625 INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.
16:06:11.759 INFO  - Report file [D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule\coden
arc\report1.xml] created.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=2; p3=2) 4140ms
16:06:11.764 INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules
16:06:11.765 INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groo
vymodule\codenarc\profile.xml]
16:06:11.869 INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.
16:06:15.067 INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.
16:06:17.707 INFO  - Report file [D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule\coden
arc\report2.xml] created.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=17; p3=13) 3298ms
16:06:17.710 INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules
16:06:17.711 INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groo
vymodule\codenarc\profile.xml]
16:06:17.826 INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.
16:06:17.837 INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.
16:06:18.969 INFO  - Report file [D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule\coden
arc\report3.xml] created.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 127ms
16:06:18.972 INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules
16:06:18.973 INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groo
vymodule\codenarc\profile.xml]
16:06:19.040 INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.
16:06:19.167 INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.
16:06:19.532 INFO  - Report file [D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule\coden
arc\report4.xml] created.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=2) 195ms
16:06:19.537 INFO  - Loaded properties file in 1ms; 346 rules
16:06:19.540 INFO  - Loading ruleset from [file:D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groo
vymodule\codenarc\profile.xml]
16:06:19.586 INFO  - RuleSet configuration properties file [codenarc.properties] not found.
16:06:19.774 INFO  - No custom message bundle found for [codenarc-messages]. Using default messages.
16:06:20.092 INFO  - Report file [D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-groovymodule\coden
arc\report5.xml] created.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=4; p3=38) 233ms
16:06:20.765 INFO  - Sensor CodeNarc (done) | time=16048ms
16:06:20.766 INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor
16:06:21.158 INFO  - GMetrics completed: 237ms
16:06:21.203 INFO  - Sensor GroovySensor (done) | time=437ms
16:06:21.204 INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor
16:06:21.205 INFO  - Analyzing Cobertura report: target/test-reports/cobertura/coverage.xml
16:06:21.377 INFO  - Sensor Groovy CoberturaSensor (done) | time=173ms
16:06:21.378 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
16:06:21.414 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=36ms
16:06:21.415 INFO  - Sensor GroovySurefireSensor
16:06:21.417 INFO  - parsing D:\Build\ParentProject\ProjectA\target\test-reports
16:06:21.418 INFO  - Sensor GroovySurefireSensor (done) | time=3ms
16:06:21.419 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
16:06:21.420 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for grvy
16:06:21.421 INFO  - Cross-project analysis enabled
16:06:21.760 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=341ms
16:06:21.769 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:06:21.853 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-01)
16:06:21.861 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-01, analysis of Mon Aug 31 01:18:52 CEST 2015)
16:06:21.864 INFO  - Compare over 21 days (2015-09-10, analysis of Wed Sep 09 01:18:12 CEST 2015)
16:06:22.556 INFO  - Execute decorators...
16:06:24.684 INFO  - -------------  Scan ProjectA-javascriptmodule
16:06:24.686 INFO  - Load module settings
16:06:24.727 INFO  - Language is forced to js
16:06:24.744 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\ProjectA
16:06:24.745 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-javascriptmodule
16:06:24.746 INFO  - Source paths: grails-app, web-app/js
16:06:24.747 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_EN
16:06:24.748 INFO  - Index files
16:06:24.749 INFO  - Excluded sources:
16:06:24.750 INFO  -   web-app/js/lib/**/*
16:06:24.815 INFO  - 9 files indexed
16:06:24.816 INFO  - 3 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
16:06:24.903 INFO  - Quality profile for js: ParentProject
16:06:24.948 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
16:06:24.952 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=4ms
16:06:24.953 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
16:06:24.954 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=1ms
16:06:24.954 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
16:06:25.024 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=70ms
16:06:25.031 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
16:06:25.040 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=9ms
16:06:25.043 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
16:06:25.096 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=53ms
16:06:25.097 INFO  - Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor
16:06:25.101 INFO  - 9 source files to be analyzed
16:06:26.722 INFO  - Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor (done) | time=1625ms
16:06:26.723 INFO  - 9/9 source files have been analyzed
16:06:26.724 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
16:06:26.732 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=8ms
16:06:26.733 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.UTCoverageSensor@4d2f36b2
16:06:26.733 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.UTCoverageSensor@4d2f36b2 (done) | time=0ms
16:06:26.734 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.ITCoverageSensor@56b007b4
16:06:26.735 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.javascript.lcov.ITCoverageSensor@56b007b4 (done) | time=1ms
16:06:26.735 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
16:06:26.736 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for js
16:06:26.736 INFO  - Cross-project analysis enabled
16:06:27.151 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=416ms
16:06:27.153 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:06:27.159 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-01)
16:06:27.161 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-01, analysis of Mon Aug 31 01:18:52 CEST 2015)
16:06:27.163 INFO  - Compare over 21 days (2015-09-10, analysis of Wed Sep 09 01:18:12 CEST 2015)
16:06:27.518 INFO  - Execute decorators...
16:06:27.916 INFO  - -------------  Scan ProjectA-webmodule
16:06:27.918 INFO  - Load module settings
16:06:27.949 INFO  - Language is forced to web
16:06:27.968 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\ProjectA
16:06:27.969 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA_ProjectA-webmodule
16:06:27.970 INFO  - Source paths: grails-app/views
16:06:27.970 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_EN
16:06:27.971 INFO  - Index files
16:06:27.972 INFO  - Excluded sources:
16:06:27.973 INFO  -   web-app/js/jquery/**
16:06:28.027 INFO  - 28 files indexed
16:06:28.028 INFO  - 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
16:06:28.273 INFO  - Quality profile for web: ParentProject
16:06:28.306 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
16:06:28.312 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=6ms
16:06:28.312 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
16:06:28.313 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=1ms
16:06:28.314 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
16:06:28.409 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=95ms
16:06:28.410 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
16:06:28.413 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=3ms
16:06:28.414 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
16:06:28.424 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=10ms
16:06:28.424 INFO  - Sensor WebSensor
16:06:28.722 INFO  - Sensor WebSensor (done) | time=298ms
16:06:28.723 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
16:06:28.738 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=15ms
16:06:28.739 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
16:06:28.740 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for web
16:06:28.740 INFO  - Cross-project analysis enabled
16:06:29.201 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=462ms
16:06:29.203 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:06:29.207 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-01)
16:06:29.209 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-01, analysis of Mon Aug 31 01:18:52 CEST 2015)
16:06:29.211 INFO  - Compare over 21 days (2015-09-10, analysis of Wed Sep 09 01:18:12 CEST 2015)
16:06:29.522 INFO  - Execute decorators...
16:06:31.389 INFO  - -------------  Scan ProjectA
16:06:31.391 INFO  - Load module settings
16:06:31.440 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\ProjectA
16:06:31.441 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar\ParentProject_ProjectA
16:06:31.442 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_EN
16:06:31.474 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
16:06:31.474 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=0ms
16:06:31.475 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
16:06:31.513 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=38ms
16:06:31.514 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
16:06:31.517 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=3ms
16:06:31.518 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
16:06:31.528 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=10ms
16:06:31.529 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
16:06:31.530 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1ms
16:06:31.530 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
16:06:31.531 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=1ms
16:06:31.532 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:06:31.537 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-01)
16:06:31.538 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-01, analysis of Mon Aug 31 01:18:52 CEST 2015)
16:06:31.540 INFO  - Compare over 21 days (2015-09-10, analysis of Wed Sep 09 01:18:12 CEST 2015)
16:06:31.808 INFO  - Execute decorators...
16:06:31.932 INFO  - -------------  Scan ParentProject SonarQube Runner
16:06:31.934 INFO  - Load module settings
16:06:31.985 INFO  - Base dir: D:\Build\ParentProject
16:06:31.986 INFO  - Working dir: D:\Build\ParentProject\.sonar
16:06:31.986 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_EN
16:06:32.020 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
16:06:32.021 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=1ms
16:06:32.021 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
16:06:32.062 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=41ms
16:06:32.063 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
16:06:32.067 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=4ms
16:06:32.067 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
16:06:32.077 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=10ms
16:06:32.078 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
16:06:32.078 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
16:06:32.079 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
16:06:32.079 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
16:06:32.081 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
16:06:32.086 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-10-01)
16:06:32.088 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-09-01, analysis of Mon Aug 31 01:18:52 CEST 2015)
16:06:32.090 INFO  - Compare over 21 days (2015-09-10, analysis of Wed Sep 09 01:18:12 CEST 2015)
16:06:32.280 INFO  - Execute decorators...
16:06:32.437 INFO  - Store results in database
16:06:34.455 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 269ms, dir size=85 KB
16:06:34.762 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 305ms, zip size=57 KB
16:06:35.137 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 374ms
16:06:35.138 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://server/dashboard/index/ParentProject
16:06:35.139 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 56.500s
Final Memory: 73M/1274M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are no errors thrown and as per the logs, the cobertura report files were found and read. But, in the SonarQube screen, the coverage section is empty.

[image: SonarQube 5.1.2 Screenshot showing empty coverage]

Can anyone provide any help in this?

****UPDATE****:
Coverage.xml contents (truncated):

```
<coverage line-rate="0.1625615763546798" branch-rate="0.034403669724770644" lines-covered="33" lines-valid="203" branches-covered="15" branches-valid="436" complexity="0.0" version="2.0.3" timestamp="1444086827204">
  <sources>
    <source>
      D:/Build/ParentProject/grails-app/services
    </source>
    <source>
      D:/Build/ParentProject/src/groovy
    </source>
    <source>
      D:/Build/ParentProject/grails-app/taglib
    </source>
    <source>
      D:/Build/ParentProject/grails-app/controllers
    </source>
  </sources>
  <packages>
    <package name="" line-rate="0.5" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="GrailsMelodyConfig" filename="GrailsMelodyConfig.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="run" signature="()Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="24" hits="1" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="24" hits="1" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="HelpContextFilters" filename="HelpContextFilters.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines/>
        </class>
        <class name="Filters" filename="Filters.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines/>
        </class>
        <class name="Filters$_closure1" filename="Filters.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="doCall" signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="5" hits="1" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="5" hits="1" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="Filters$_closure1$_closure2" filename="Filters.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="doCall" signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="6" hits="1" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="6" hits="1" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="Filters$_closure1$_closure2$_closure3" filename="Filters.groovy" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="doCall" signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="7" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
                  <conditions>
                    <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                  </conditions>
                </line>
                <line number="8" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/4)">
                  <conditions>
                    <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                    <condition number="1" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                  </conditions>
                </line>
                <line number="9" hits="0" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="7" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/2)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="8" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/4)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                <condition number="1" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="9" hits="0" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    <package name="com" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
      <classes>
        <class name="com.CustomHtmlTagLib" filename="com/CustomHtmlTagLib.groovy" line-rate="1.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods/>
          <lines/>
        </class>
        <class name="com.CustomHtmlTagLib$_closure1" filename="com/CustomHtmlTagLib.groovy" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="doCall" signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="0.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="16" hits="0" branch="false"/>
                <line number="18" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/4)">
                  <conditions>
                    <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                    <condition number="1" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                  </conditions>
                </line>
                <line number="19" hits="0" branch="false"/>
                <line number="21" hits="0" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="16" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="18" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="0% (0/4)">
              <conditions>
                <condition number="0" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
                <condition number="1" type="jump" coverage="0%"/>
              </conditions>
            </line>
            <line number="19" hits="0" branch="false"/>
            <line number="21" hits="0" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
        <class name="com.CustomHtmlTagLib$_closure2" filename="com/CustomHtmlTagLib.groovy" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="1.0" complexity="0.0">
          <methods>
            <method name="doCall" signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;" line-rate="0.0" branch-rate="1.0">
              <lines>
                <line number="26" hits="0" branch="false"/>
              </lines>
            </method>
          </methods>
          <lines>
            <line number="26" hits="0" branch="false"/>
          </lines>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </package>
    ... TRUNCATED ...
  </packages>
</coverage>
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your coverage.xml file ? how are you generating cobertura.ser and coverage.xml (maven plugin?)

Comment: I am using Jenkins to generate the coverage.xml and its working properly as Jenkins shows the coverages. I will update the question with the contents from coverage.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got an answer to the above problem. Posting it here so that it can be helpful to others.

In the coverage.xml, for some of the source files, the line number gets evaluated to be '0' like below:

```
<line number="0" hits="0" branch="true" condition-coverage="33% (1/3)">
  <conditions>
    <condition number="0" type="switch" coverage="33%"/>
  </conditions>
</line>
```

There are two solutions to handle the same:

1. Downgrade the cobertura plugin which is being used to generate the
   coverage.xml and check if the coverage.xml still generates the above
   line

OR

2. Exclude the file from the coverage as below in BuildConfig.groovy
   (as I am using Grails application):

   coverage {
        exclusions = [ "FileA*", "FileB*", "**/package/*"]
   }

More info:

- http://dublintech.blogspot.nl/2015/06/problems-with-cobertura-and-sonar-51.html
- http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-with-SourcePersister-since-5-1-td5034233.html

Even though they were facing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, I tried their solution and it worked for me too.

**UPDATE**: I had also reverted the Sonarqube Groovy plugin back to 1.0.1 from 1.2 and it also helped along with the above solution. The above solution wont work with Sonarqube Groovy plugin 1.2.

**UPDATE 2**: I created a small groovy code which would run at end of coverage.xml creation and before the running the sonar-runner. This groovy code iterates through all the coverage.xml created and removes the nodes containing the line number="0". This way, the files are a part of coverage as well and nothing is excluded.